# How to process json from Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps-api-3, coldfusion

From https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/

If I enter:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Hickory+NC&destinations=Niagra+Falls+NY&sensor=false&units=imperial
```

Then I get:

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Niagara Falls, NY, USA" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Hickory, NC, USA" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "667 mi",
                  "value" : 1072719
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "11 hours 21 mins",
                  "value" : 40835
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

But if I issue this command:

```
<cfhttp method="get" result="myContent" url="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json">
    <cfhttpparam type="url" name="origins" value="Hickory+NC">
    <cfhttpparam type="url" name="destinations" value="Niagra+Falls+NY">
    <cfhttpparam type="url" name="sensor" value="false">
    <cfhttpparam type="url" name="units" value="imperial">
</cfhttp>
<cfdump var="#myContent#">
```

Then I get back a structure with a StatusCode=200OK, but Text=NO.

Comment: I'd try this myself but I'm on my phone. Try *not* URL encoding your values in the param tags. Just use a space, not a +, and see if you get different results.

Comment: Make sure you're looking at myContent.Filecontent.  I ran your code and got a valid result.  No modifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add  `getAsBinary="never"` to your cfhttp

```
<cfhttp method="get" result="myContent" url="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json" getAsBinary="never">
    <cfhttpparam type="url" name="origins" value="Hickory+NC">
    <cfhttpparam type="url" name="destinations" value="Niagra+Falls+NY">
    <cfhttpparam type="url" name="sensor" value="false">
    <cfhttpparam type="url" name="units" value="imperial">
</cfhttp>
<cfdump var="#myContent#">
```

Returns me this in the myContent.FileContent

```
 {
    "destination_addresses": ["Niagara Falls, NY, USA"],
    "origin_addresses": ["Hickory, NC, USA"],
    "rows": [{
        "elements": [{
            "distance": {
                "text": "667 mi",
                "value": 1072719
            },
            "duration": {
                "text": "11 hours 21 mins",
                "value": 40835
            },
            "status": "OK"
        }]
    }],
    "status": "OK"
}
```